# How to pip install private repo on python Docker

Tags: docker, github, ssh, docker-compose, pip

How can I install a private repo inside a python image docker? I tried many alternatives but all were unsuccesful. Seems I cant get to set ssh credentials inside a python based image.

My Docker image:

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

# Django files
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

the requirements file has:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/my_repo_name.git@dev
```

And build is triggered from aocker compose file:

```
....
django_service:
    build: 
        context: ..
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - static_data:/vol/web
    environment: 
        - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}

    depends_on: 
 ....
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use https instead of ssh: `git clone https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/username/my_repo_name.git@dev` you can set the token inside the Dockerfile as `ARG GH_TOKEN` - to keep the token outside the Dockerfile you can build your docker image with passing the arg like this `--build-arg GH_TOKEN=MY_TOKEN`

Comment: @PamelaSarkisyan I think you should post this as answer

Comment: sure I will do it now, I hope this worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `https` instead of `ssh:`
`git clone https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/username/my_repo_name.git@dev`

To set the token *inside* the Dockerfile use: `ARG GH_TOKEN`
To keep the token *outside* the Dockerfile you can build your docker
image with passing the arg like this `--build-arg GH_TOKEN=MY_TOKEN`